# How to retrive description of page of menu in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

In the top menu i want to add description of parent ul in menu. How to retrive parent page description in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your question properly but if you have submenu and you want to show description of the parent menu item of sub-menu and your menu item has a page(not custom menu item) just add description in content area that's all.

When you click parent ul menu item, it will show by theme page.php page.
 If my answer is not what you want, please explain

Comment: my require mentioned in following url image (http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1413883/dce91e24569a225827866de4ee50630d)     In which show i need this description show as write in parent description